# I need to get an array from my app in an email with PHP

Tags: php, ios, swift

I have a tableview and want to get that data send by email by click on a button with PHP. The tableview data comes from a `array`.  I manage to get a variable in my email as you see below in the code but not an array (like the data from my tableview)  Can someone help me?

```
func postToServerFunction() {

    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.aaa.com/be/file.php")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myUrl! as URL)
     let userTotal = String(cartBrain.total)
    var bodyData = "data=\(userTotal)"
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)

}
```

and my PHP code:

```
<?php
$postVar = $_POST['data'];
if(!empty($postVar)){
    mail(“userEmail”,”email verzonden", $postVar);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong `”` in your code so it is not working.

```
$postVar = $_POST['data'];
if(!empty($postVar)){
    mail("userEmail","email verzonden", $postVar); // replace ” with " 
}
```